# Why this show up when I delete a video file from my app

Tags: android, file

I use this code to delete file at Download/My Videos/blahblah.mp4

```
File file = new File(myfilePath);
file.delete();
```

It delete from storage but in social app it show error loading media instead of removing itself.
But after phone reboot those error file are gone. What I want is to remove those error file without needed to reboot phone. I have tested with MX player app after I delete video from mx player video instantly remove form everywhere not showing error loading media like when I delete form my app.

Got Error File like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I just solve it by using MediaScannerConnection